# ASP.Net Error Code 128

Tags: asp.net, publishing

I have a ASP.Net Application which runs fine on my development machine, however, when publishing to server, I get this error

Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code 128.

I don't know why can this be happening
I think it can be related to cached dll's on server, is there any way to clear this cache?

Whatever help will be appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT**

¿The IIS reset will be resetting other IIS applications? We have other applications running on the same IIS Server. I think it will So I wouldn't think it's a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try and run the command below in a command prompt window:

```
iisreset
```